React Navbar Mobile Menu Background Does Not Cover Full Page Width
Problem:
I'm having trouble with my React Navbar component. When I decrease the screen width, the mobile nav menu opens up, but the #242424 background doesn't cover the entire width of the page. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

My Code:
Navbar.js:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';
import { Button } from './Button.js';

function Navbar() {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const [button, setButton] = useState(true);
    
    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
    const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

    const showButton = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 850) {
            setButton(false);
        } else {
            setButton(true);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        showButton();
        window.addEventListener('resize', showButton);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', showButton);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="navbar-container">
                    <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">
                        Portfolio <i className="fa-solid fa-user-secret" />
                    </Link>
                    <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
                        <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                    </div>
                    <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Home
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/work' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Work
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/skills' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Skills
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/contact' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Contact
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/sign-up' className='nav-links-mobile' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Sign Up
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    {button && <Button buttonStyle='btn--outline'>SIGN IN</Button>}
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;

Navbar.css
.navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  
  .navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /* height: 100px; */
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  .navbar-logo {
    color: #fff;
    justify-self: start;
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .fa-user-secret {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  
  .nav-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50vw;
    justify-content: end;
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    height: 65px;
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  
  .nav-links {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    /* align-items: center; */
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3.37rem 0.5rem;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav-links:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  }
  
  .fa-bars {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .nav-links-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    .NavbarItems {
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .nav-menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
      /* height: 60.5vh; */
      position: absolute;
      top: 80px;
      left: -100%;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .nav-menu.active {
      background: #242222;
      left: 0;
      padding-right: none;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      /* height: calc(100vh - 80px); */
    }
  
    .nav-links {
      top: 0;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1rem;
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
    }
  
    .nav-links:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #242424;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  
    .navbar-logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translate(25%, 50%);
    }
  
    .menu-icon {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  
    .fa-times {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
  
    .nav-links-mobile {

      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0.4rem auto;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 60%;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px 30px;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }
  
    .nav-links-mobile:hover {
      background: #fff;
      color: #242424;
      transition: 250ms;
    }

  }

App.js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

What I've Tried:
I have tried changing the height of the .nav-menu.active as calc(100vh - 80px);
But then it gives this result:

Somehow, the button is sticking to the bottom.
If you want anything extra to understand, I will provide it immediately!

You have justify-content set to flex-end. If you reinsert height: calc(100vh - 80px); and set justify-content to flex-start, it will be at the top instead of the bottom. So:
ul.nav-menu.active {
     height: calc(100vh - 80px); 
    justify-content: flex-start;
}


Thanks! I tried it with padding-bottom, but your method is even better!
